# How to build a query to get objects that have other objects linked via ProxyConnector

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

I need a query to get a list of objects that connect to ADU1 (in image). In this list I only need the name of the object. This I'm already doing. However, if there is a ProxyConnector, like in the image, I need the list to have also the object to which the trace connector is linked to.

The goal is that this query is used to populate a fragment of a doc template.

Anyone has any ideas or hints? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there. As you have noticed the «trace» connector connects object `Phase1` with an invisible object with both `name` and `object_type` set to `ProxyConnector`

This ProxyConnector record connects to your association between `ADU1` and `Object 1` with the field `Classifier_guid`. This corresponds to the `ea_guid` of the association.

So in order to get both `Object 1` as `Phase1` you can use a query like this

```
select o2.name
from t_object o 
inner join t_connector c on o.Object_ID in (c.Start_Object_ID, c.End_Object_ID)
inner join t_object prx on prx.Classifier_guid = c.ea_guid
inner join t_connector pc on prx.Object_ID in (pc.Start_Object_ID, pc.End_Object_ID)
left join t_object o2 on o2.Object_ID in  (pc.Start_Object_ID, pc.End_Object_ID)
                            and o2.Object_ID <> prx.Object_ID
where o.ea_guid = '{1CAC051A-142D-4430-9E9D-F323C38FE547}' --guid of ADU1
union
select o2.name
from t_object o 
inner join t_connector c on o.Object_ID in (c.Start_Object_ID, c.End_Object_ID)
inner join t_object o2 on o2.Object_ID in  (c.Start_Object_ID, c.End_Object_ID)
                            and o2.Object_ID <> o.Object_ID
where o.ea_guid = '{1CAC051A-142D-4430-9E9D-F323C38FE547}' --guid of ADU1
```

The first query will get you the element connected through the proxy connector, the second query gets you the elements connected the regular way.

*This query uses SQL Server syntax. You might need to add a bunch of parentheses to translate this to MS Access syntax (used on .eap and .eapx files)*

Comment: This really helped a lot. Thank you!